# this thing i'm doing wants python 2to3. i already have that. what do i do?

Tags: python, pip, python-2to3

I'm trying to install the package pyminifier at the command prompt, this happens:

```
C:\Users\[my name]\Downloads\JKLMBombpartyHelper-master\JKLMBombpartyHelper-master>python -m pip install pyminifier
Collecting pyminifier
  Using cached pyminifier-2.1.tar.gz (47 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [3 lines of output]
      Python 3.X support requires the 2to3 tool.
      It normally comes with Python 3.X but (apparenty) not on your distribution.
      Please find out what package you need to get 2to3and install it.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

However, if I attempt to install `2to3` using `pip install 2to3`, I find that it is already installed:

```
Requirement already satisfied: 2to3 in c:\users\[my name]\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (1.0)
```

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: After reading your entire question, I have no idea what you're asking.  You need to explain better.

Comment: @Friedrich my bad, image removed

Comment: Please post code that reproduces the problem. The previous comment meant that you should [edit] your question to include the code as text, not remove it entirely.

Comment: @MarkRansom i'm trying to set up a program, i run pip install -r requirements.txt (i don't know if that's helpful)
i get this error
i'm not sure what it wants me to do
i don't know what more i can explain

Comment: Exactly what package are you trying to install? There is a pretty good chance that it simply is no longer supported on modern versions of Python. `2to3` is an old tool for updating old code to be compatible; it's in the process of being deprecated.

Comment: See deprecation notice https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html

Comment: @KarlKnechtel as in what i'm trying to install that triggers the error? "-r requirements.txt".

Comment: Yes. Edit your question to include your requirements file

Comment: @OneCricketeer the deprecation notice says it doesn't work starting from 3.11, i'm using 3.10.6.

Comment: "-r requirements.txt" means that `pip` will read a file that lists some packages to install. Please try to figure out **which one** is causing the problem when `pip` tries to install it, and **tell us** what it is.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel (it's pyminifier)

Comment: Are you using the exact same interpreter to install dependencies and to run the code? -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: @sinoroc ran python -m pip install pyminifier, same error message

Comment: This is not the full console output trace. Maybe it would be helpful to have more context of where that error message comes from. -- It could be that something is being run in a separate environment, as is typically the case when building dependencies. I can imagine that `pyminifier` (or whatever other dependency is being built) has build dpeendencies that require `2to3` but do not declare it.

Comment: @sinoroc you mean, like, you want me to show the entire download process thingy and not just the error message?

Comment: @envi I think it could be helpful, yes. Maybe we won't find anything, but now we do not even know what command was being executed when the error message happened. We do not know what *pip* was doing at that moment, which dependency or build dependency it was trying to build or install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that it fails because *pip* tries to build a *wheel* of *pyminifier* in an isolated build environment and fails because there is no *2to3* in that build environment. This is a very old, outdated, unmaintained, and not well-behaved library. If I were you I would not use it at all, if I could.

If you really depend on that library, you could try to tell *pip* to install it without "*build isolation*", with `python -m pip install --no-build-isolation --no-deps pyminifier`. I am not sure it would help. Maybe it would be better to use an old Python version (not sure which Python version you are using right now). Honestly, I would rather not use this library at all if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools==57.5.0
```

then install

```
pip3 install pyminifier
```

worked!!

- Versions are
- `python3 --version`

> Python 3.9.16

- `pip3 --version`

> pip 23.1.2